Unable to install pipewire on Linux Lite 7.0 (Ubuntu 24.04 Noble)
I'm trying to install pipewire on Ubuntu 24.04 Noble for a while now, but there is always recursive unmet dependencies error. I did add the ppa, but it's didn't help.
$ apt install pipewire
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpipewire-0.3-modules : Depends: libsnapd-glib1 (>= 1.59) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


What happens when you try installing libsnapd-glib1 before your "fix?"

Pipewire can be installed by installing the missing dependencies libsnapd-glib1, directly libsnapd-glib1 from apt isn't working for me, so I decided to look for it's deb packages, and found it at http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/snapd-glib/libsnapd-glib1_1.60-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
just download the deb package then dpkg -i package_name, the dependency error is solved and pipewire can be installed

This answer, although it fixed your issue, was not the correct approach.  It is ill advised to "mix" distribution repositories.  Your original Question presupposes pipewire is supported on LinuxLite, which doesn't seem to be the case.  If pipewire is available in the LinuxLite repository, then this needs to be reported to the maintainer for either an addition to the repo or a version bump.  On the other hand, if pipewire isn't supported/in the repo, it needs to be removed.
